# sys/socket.h missing in WinObjC?

Tags: winobjc

I've been trying to compile a simple Objective-C project that uses the Reachability library & the compile stops at the sys/socket.h import. Any ideas?

Comment: Your code is wrong, that is the answer. You can't possibly be helped without knowing what you have.

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/fdierick/JustReachability

Contains 2 branches with a project with just Reachability and nothing more. The "justsockets" branch only imports sys/socket.h

Exact error message when compiling in VS15 is "fatal error: sys/socket.h file not found"